# How to access navigation properties in EF using repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Context: ASP.NET web application

The Base Repository (abstract class) implements the needed base functionality from which all other repositories inherit:
i.e.
-PersonRepo
-AddressRepo

**EDIT:**
Where do you place the code which queries several db tables and some of them are not directly related as navigation property in the respective repository?

Now, what is the best way to access the navigation properties?
It is very cumbersome when using the repository pattern.
If there is not a convenient solution for this, I will stick to my old DAL layer with everything inside and work with DbContext directly.

I just came up with a temporary solution for accessing navigation properties in my PersonRepository implementation:

```
public Person InsertNewPersonWithAddress(Person p, Address addr)
        {
            this.Insert(p); // insert person
            var ar = new AddressRepository(this.ctx);
            ar.Insert(addr);  // insert address
            this.Addresses(p).Add(addr);  // add address to person

            return p;
        }

        /* Navigation Properties */ 
        ICollection<Address> Addresses(Person p)
        {
            return ctx.Entry<Person>(p).Collection<Address>("Addresses").CurrentValue;
        }
```

**Base Repository** class implements the following interface

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> All();
        IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T Insert(T entity);
        IEnumerable<T> InsertMultiple(IEnumerable<T> items);
        T Delete(T entity);
        IEnumerable<T> DeleteMultiple(IEnumerable<T> items);
        T Update(T entity);
        IEnumerable<T> UpdateMultiple(IEnumerable<T> items);
        void Save();
    }
```

DB-Design:

Person --> PersonAddress(junction table) <-- Address

Any intelligent solution for this problem?

Comment: What would be the advantage of using repository pattern with EF? Read http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework/.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about this the wrong way.  The navigation property is a property of the Entity, not a property of the Repository.  You don't need to instantiate a Repository for the navigation property, it can be added directly to the Entity.

```
public Person InsertNewPersonWithAddress(Person p, Address addr)
{
    p.Address = addr;
    this.Insert(p); // insert person

    return p;
}
```

Now, if you are inserting a new `Person` but want it attached to an existing `Address` (rather than inserting a new copy of both), you can expose the `AddressId` FK as a property on the `Person` Entity, and pass in the `FK` value to do the link.  In either case, it's not necessary for this Repository to need access to the other.

Comment: Just fyi, I want to insert a new person with a new address. Disconnected scenario. I will try your approach now..

Comment: Ok, this works in this scenario and I hope in all others too :-).
I was thinking that I must do this way:

` //ctx.Persons.Attach(p);
   //ctx.Entry<Person>(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

   //ctx.Addresses.Attach(addr);
   //ctx.Entry<Address>(addr).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

   //p.Addresses.Add(addr);`